# Are nullable properties, or properties allowed to be null, code smell (in OOP languages)?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

I often see `class`es like

```
public class Person
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }

    string MiddleName { get; set; }

    string LastName { get; set; }

    int Age { get; set; }
}
```

where one of the properties, say `MiddleName` in this example (because some people aren't given a middle name at birth), is allowed to be `null`. In my opinion this is wrong because any consumers of the class have to know that the property "might" be null and perform checks like

```
public void PrintName(Person p)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.FirstName);

    if (p.MiddleName != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.MiddleName);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(p.LastName);
}
```

How I handle this is by using composition like

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string FirstName { get; }

    string LastName { get; }

    int Age { get; }
}

public interface IMiddleNamed
{
    string MiddleName { get; }
}
```

and

```
public void PrintName(IPerson p)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.FirstName);

    if (p is IMiddleNamed)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((p as IMiddleNamed).MiddleName);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(p.LastName);
}
```

That is the case even if my models represent data contracts (e.g. "value bags" that are serialized/deserialized through inter-service communication).

In the same way I avoid classes that has `null`-able value types like

```
public class Something
{
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }

    public double? SomeDouble { get; }
}
```

for the same reason.

However I'm wondering if this is like "OOP overengineering" as it clearly adds a lot of development time.

Comment: Welcome to c#8 proposals for nullable reference types: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/15/nullable-reference-types-in-csharp/

Comment: The next version of the C# language will have something that is (rather confusingly) known as _"Nullable reference types"_ that will simplify the specification of where `null` is allowed and make null handling more explicit (with a lot of it done by the compiler).  Until then, it's probably over-engineering

Comment: Coding style questions are generally off-topic as too broad/opinion-based for SO. You may want to check if you can make your questions suitable for [softwareengineering.se] (also I expect there are plenty of existing questions about nullable values, null objects and the like - make sure to search there first).

Comment: You are overcomplicating things. Keep it simple. I would say you dont even need MiddleName property. Users are fine putting their middle name with their first name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw the current answers are about String (such as string class in c# handles it), but I guess your question covers all possible nullable objects.

**1) First off, about the ?? operator** suggested in another answer:
It will allow your code to live with null objects but at some point, you usually still have to handle the null case

**example:**

```
if(a != null && a.b != null and a.b.c != null) 
{
    a.b.c.doSomething();
}
```

will become

```
if(a?.b?.c? != null)
{
    a.b.c.doSomething();
}
```

Yes, it is a bit better but doesn't really solve your problem.

**2) Code architecture proposition**

I found that usually, allowing `null` means that your class serves several purposes, and carry more state. In this example, your class can represent both 'A name with middle name' or 'a name without a full name'. Here are some ideas about code architecture

- Usually, it means this class does too many things. Of course in your example the class is small. But in everyday life, having a member that can be null usually means that the class is too big and supports too many features. One class should have only one purpose. See the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
- In some case (like in the example), you could think that you don't want to split the class because it makes sense as is. Then you could try to see if there is a way to think this class with the same functionalities, witout handling a special case.

In your example you could do:

```
public class Person
{
    string[] FirstNames { get; set {if(value == null) FirstName } = new string[]{};

    string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Now there is no special case. All function must take in account an array of names, that could have a size of one.

- If you really, really want a null object, you can also put the logique that handles it inside the class and be sure that noone else accesses the null object. But this could lead to having a ton of logique in the same class so that is not the best solution

In your example you could do

```
public class Person
{
    private string FirstName { get; set {if(value == null) FirstName } = string.Empty;

    private string MiddleName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    int Age { get; set; }

    public string getName()
    {
        // Here handle the null case
    }
}
```

You can see how this puts more logique in the class.

- Finally, you can read about the [Null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern). This pattern requires more code but allows you to replace `null` by an actual instance of the object that will not crash when you call functions on them. I never actively used it because I usually manage to get cleaner code with the prinicples above, but you might find a case where this is useful.

Below a Null Object implementation example from wikipedia

```
/* Null object pattern implementation:
 */
using System;

// Animal interface is the key to compatibility for Animal implementations below.
interface IAnimal
{
    void MakeSound();
}

// Animal is the base case.
abstract class Animal : IAnimal
{
    // A shared instance that can be used for comparisons
    public static readonly IAnimal Null = new NullAnimal();

    // The Null Case: this NullAnimal class should be used in place of C# null keyword.
    private class NullAnimal : Animal
    {
        public override void MakeSound()
        {
            // Purposefully provides no behaviour.
        }
    }
    public abstract void MakeSound();
}

// Dog is a real animal.
class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public void MakeSound()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Woof!");
    }
}

/* =========================
 * Simplistic usage example in a Main entry point.
 */
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IAnimal dog = new Dog();
        dog.MakeSound(); // outputs "Woof!"

        /* Instead of using C# null, use the Animal.Null instance.
         * This example is simplistic but conveys the idea that if the         Animal.Null instance is used then the program
         * will never experience a .NET System.NullReferenceException at runtime, unlike if C# null were used.
         */
        IAnimal unknown = Animal.Null;  //<< replaces: IAnimal unknown = null;
    unknown.MakeSound(); // outputs nothing, but does not throw a runtime exception        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes nulls are useful for sure, such as when you have an object that represents a set of answers to questions, where e.g. bool? TrueFalseAnswer == null would imply that the question was not answered, rather than defaulting to false, or string name == null would imply that the name field was not filled out, etc..

As far as your classes go, you can at least initialize them to empty strings.

```
public class Person
{
    string FirstName { get; set {if(value == null) FirstName } = string.Empty;

    string MiddleName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Also, I don't think this is what you mean exactly, but:

```
string s = null;
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Outputs a new line to console and does not cause an error.

Then again, it's also pretty easy to type:

```
Person p = new Person();
//if(p == null || p.MiddleName == null) s = "";
string s = p?.MiddleName ?? "";
```

So, nulls are useful and C# makes it super easy to check for them.